# Client Access License (CAL) in SQL Server 2005 standard Edition

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am using SQL server 2005 Standard Edition SP3 for installing my application DB. 
My SQL installation returns License type is "DISABLED" and number of Licenses (CALs) is "NULL".

I have done performance testing on my webmodule pointing to this DB using load runner tool.
Simultaneous connections on the web module is limited to around 25.

Kindly clarify if the  simultaneous connection restrictions is due to the CALs count.
Also need clarity on how CAL count will affect the web module of an application.

Thanks in Advance.

Siva.S.

Answer (score 0):

CAL count does not affect performance whatsoever, nor does it even enforce the number of concurrent connections allowed to SQL Server.  This is just a data point for the auditors to check if you are conforming to your license.

It appears you have installed SQL Server from an MSDN installation, which is why license type = "DISABLED" and CAL count is empty.